# Android - testing Google Map info window click

Tags: android, google-maps, testing, android-espresso, android-uiautomator

I'm writing tests for my app and I'm stuck with testing `GoogleMap`. Clicking on Marker was easy using `UiAutomator`, but it seems that it's impossible to click on info window.

This is how I make test click on `Marker`:

```
UiDevice device = UiDevice.getInstance(InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation());
UiObject marker = device.findObject(new UiSelector().descriptionContains(MARKER_TITLE));
```

I've tried using Android Device Monitor and dumping view hierarchy but it seems like that view (info window) isn't there.

Here is how the screen that I'm trying to test looks like:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/FuxHG.png

Any idea on how to click on info window using `Espresso` or `UiAutomator`?

Answer (score 1):

The info window that is drawn is not a live view. The view is rendered as an image (using View.draw(Canvas)) at the time it is returned. This means that you won't be able to find it as an Object.

As you can listen to a generic click event on the whole info window, you might be able to touch is using its coordinates calculated as an offset from the marker.

Answer (score 0):

Some webviews cant be automated using `uiautomator`. Whatever ui elements appearing in `uiautomatorviewer` can automate. Just check `uiautomatorviewer` first. If it does not appear in viewer, one work around is `adb shell input tap <x> <y>`. where x,y are coordinates on your screen.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by Diego Torres Milano, you can't use Espresso, because the InfoWindow is drawn as an image. But you can use UIAutomator, and assume that the Marker will be animated to the center of the screen after being clicked:

#### app/build.gradle

```
androidTestImplementation "androidx.test.uiautomator:uiautomator:2.1.3" // UIAutomator
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1' // For @RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class)
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.1'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:rules:1.1.1' // For UI Tests that use ActivityTestRule
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.1' // Espresso
```

#### MapViewTest.kt

```kotlin
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class)
class MapViewTest {
  @Rule
  @JvmField
  val activityRule: ActivityTestRule<MapViewActivity> 
    = ActivityTestRule(MapViewActivity::class.java)

  @Test
  fun mapViewUITest() {
    val twoSeconds = 2000
    val fiveSeconds = 5000

    // Wait for the Map View to load
    waitFor(fiveSeconds)

    // First of all, click on the Marker, using UIAutomator
    val device = UiDevice.getInstance(getInstrumentation())
    val marker = device.findObject(UiSelector().descriptionContains("My Marker Title"))
    marker.click()
  
    // After a marker is clicked, the MapView will automatically move the map
    // to position the Marker at the center of the screen, at 43% screen height.
    // So wait for the animation to finish first.
    waitFor(twoSeconds)
  
    // Calculate the (x,y) position of the InfoWindow, using the screen size
    val display = activityRule.activity.windowManager.defaultDisplay
    val size = Point()
    display.getRealSize(size)
    val screenWidth = size.x
    val screenHeight = size.y
    val x = screenWidth / 2
    val y = (screenHeight * 0.43).toInt()
  
    // Click on the InfoWindow, using UIAutomator
    device.click(x, y)
    waitFor(twoSeconds)

    // Add further UI tests with Espresso
  }
  
  private fun waitFor(duration: Int) = Thread.sleep(duration.toLong())
}
```